# Curl api parsing

Tags: perl

Am trying to parse curl api

but am getting this error   401 Unauthorized

i don't know where is the problem comes from.

because the authentication details are ok

this is the curl

```sh
curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/SID/Messages.json' \
   -X POST \
   --data-urlencode 'To=whatsapp:+123456789' \
   --data-urlencode 'From=whatsapp:+1234567890' \
   --data-urlencode 'Body=Your Yummy Cupcakes Company order of 1 dozen frosted cupcakes has shipped and should be delivered on July 10, 2019. Details: http://www.yummycupcakes.com/' \
   -u SID:[AuthToken]
```

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTTP::Tiny;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/SID/Messages.json";
my $json = encode_json {
To    => 'whatsapp:+256775562361',
From => 'whatsapp:+14155238886',
Body   => 'new test msg',
};

my $http = HTTP::Tiny->new(
default_headers => {
Authorization => 'SID:TOKEN',
}
);

my $response = $http->post( $url => {
content => $json,
headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' },
});

if ( $response->{'is_success'} ) {
print Dumper( decode_json $response->{'content'} );
} else {
print "$response->{'status'} $response->{'reason'}\n";
}
```

Comment: Re "*but am getting this error*", What error?

Comment: Re "*this is the curl*", Are you saying this version works? So why are you sending JSON in the Perl version?

Comment: 401 Unauthorized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the "[Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)" header isn't `<user>:<pass>` -- it's `<auth-scheme> <authorization-parameters>`.  `curl` is doing this for you, but for this it's basically:

```
Authorization: Basic <mime-encoded "<user>:<pass>">
```

I use the [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) module for this:

```
my $uri = URI->new("https://api.twilio.com/...");
$uri->userinfo("$sid:$auth");

$http->post( $uri => ... );
```